# send string through TCP (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I connected successfully to onlinenic API using TCP client, but facing an error when trying to login.

Below is my code (Username and password are demo as was provided by onlinenic)

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Xml

Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private client As New TcpClient()
    Private stream As NetworkStream
    Private PortNo As Integer = 30009
    Private testIP As String = "218.5.81.149"
    Private testID As String = "135610"
    Private testPassword As String = "654123"
    Private Function Connect() As Boolean
        client.Connect(testIP, PortNo)
        stream = client.GetStream()
        Dim responseData As String = ""
        Dim data As [Byte]() = New [Byte](255) {}
        Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        Return responseData.Contains("Your Connection with API Server is Successful")
    End Function




    Private Function Login() As Boolean
        Dim HashedPass As String = CreateMd5Hash(testPassword)
        Dim guid__1 As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
        Dim chksum As String = CreateMd5Hash(testID + HashedPass + guid__1.ToString() + "login")
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>")
        sb.Append("<request>")
        sb.Append("<category>client</category>")
        sb.Append("<action>Login</action>")
        sb.Append("<params>")
        sb.Append("<param name=""clid"">" + testID + "</param>")
        sb.Append("</params>")
        sb.Append("<cltrid>" + guid__1.ToString() + "</cltrid>")
        sb.Append("<chksum>" + chksum + "</chksum>")
        sb.Append("</request>")
        Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty
        Dim data As [Byte]()
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        Return responseData.Contains("Command completed successfully")
    End Function
```

when i try to connect using the above login() function I got the following error :

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Line 49:         Dim data As [Byte]()
Line 50:         data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())
Line 51:         stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
Line 52:         Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
Line 53:         responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
```

The error message am getting on this line :  stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=App_Web_4023pkvf   StackTrace:
>          at _Default.Login() in D:\Documents and Settings\sa\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\onlinenic_vb1\Default.aspx.vb:line 51
>          at _Default.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Documents and Settings\sa\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\onlinenic_vb1\Default.aspx.vb:line 243
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Line 51:         stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

Comment: for refernce the API am working on is : https://www.onlinenic.com/cp_english/template_api/download/API_EN_Version_2.0.pdf

Comment: Looks like "stream" is null at the point.  Are you running Connect() before Login()?

Comment: yes, I connected successfully using connect() and then trying to login() .I converted this code from other C# code.

Comment: Is this with a release build? Try with a debug build to confirm what line the exception is really occurring on.

Comment: I should mention: I ask the above because looking with Reflector shows both `data` and `stream` should not be `Nothing` by the time you get to line 51.

Comment: I updated my post with error message

Comment: I didnt solve the problem , is there any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this :

```
 Dim HashedPass As String = CreateMd5Hash(testPassword)
        Dim guid__1 As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
        Dim chksum As String = CreateMd5Hash(testID + HashedPass + guid__1.ToString() + "login")
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>")
        sb.Append("<request>")
        sb.Append("<category>client</category>")
        sb.Append("<action>Login</action>")
        sb.Append("<params>")
        sb.Append("<param name=""clid"">" + testID + "</param>")
        sb.Append("</params>")
        sb.Append("<cltrid>" + guid__1.ToString() + "</cltrid>")
        sb.Append("<chksum>" + chksum + "</chksum>")
        sb.Append("</request>")
        Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty
        Dim data As [Byte]()
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        Return responseData.Contains("Command completed successfully")
```